# Allow object as parameter only if extends particular class in php

Tags: php, class, parameters, interface, extend

How can I restrict class `method` to take only `object` of a `class` which extends a particular class?

Code:

Serializer Interface

```php
namespace App\API\Serializers;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

interface Serializer
{
    public function serialize(Model $model);
}
```

```php
namespace App\API\Serializers;

use App\API\Serializers\Serializer;
use App\Models\Article;

class MilestoneListSerializer implements Serializer
{
    public function serialize(Article $article)
    {

    }
}
```

I want to pass `Article` as parameter and It's extending `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class

Is there any way to do this, please help me.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the `Serializer interface` `serialize` method signature when you alter the parameter from `Model` to `Article`. You should keep the `Model`, and if the `Article` extends `Model`, then you will be able to pass it to the method.

Interface Serializer

```
namespace App\API\Serializers;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

interface Serializer
{
    public function serialize(Model $modelOrItsSubTypes);
}
```

MilestoneListSerializer

```
namespace App\API\Serializers;

use App\API\Serializers\Serializer;
use App\Models\Article;

class MilestoneListSerializer implements Serializer
{
    public function serialize(Model $modelOrItsSubTypes)
    {
        // ... Use Model methods here
    }
}
```

Article

```
namespace App\Somenamespace;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
    //.. Overrides here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not to do this. Interface defines the contract: all implementations of method should accept any instance of Model class. You break this contract if restrict an argument type. It is violation of the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Some languages support inversed feature: contravariance of parameters, but none admits their covariance.

You can manually check a type and throw an exception. In fact this still is LSP violation, but sometimes it may be useful. Other way is to revision your architecture and classes hierarchy.